# Error when executing using ./bin/spark-submit in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, analytics

I am getting the below error when executing the code from command line in centOS.

```
"(<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling o313.save.\n', JavaObject id=o315), <traceback object at 0x7fca49970320>)"
```

I am getting this issue only when I am submitting it through ./bin/spark-submit test.py

If I use just :  `spark-submit test.py` everything works fine. But I am not able to run the code in `yarn` with it.

I have `anaconda` installed in my machine and I think it's using the a`naconda spark-submit` in the second method.

Can anyone please suggest what to do with it? Do I have set any env variables or update the libraries?

Edit:

As per the comments providing more details about the script and versions

This is the code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,DataFrame
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler, OneHotEncoderEstimator, OneHotEncoder
import sys
from operator import add
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression,LogisticRegressionModel

path = 'hdfs://10.0.15.42/nih-poc-public-dataset/'

pipeline_path = '/opt/nih/pipeline_model'


try:   
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[8]").setAppName("sparkstream").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .config(conf = conf)\
            .getOrCreate()

    print "SparkContext Version:", sc.version  
    print "SparkContext Version:", sc.version
    print "Python version: ", sc.pythonVer
    print "Master URL to connect to: ", sc.master
    print "Path where Spark is installed on worker nodes: ", str(sc.sparkHome)
    print "Retrieve name of the Spark User running SparkContext: ", str(sc.sparkUser())
    print "Application name: ", sc.appName
    print "Application ID: ", sc.applicationId
    print "Default level of parallelism: ", sc.defaultParallelism
    print "Default number of partitions for RDDs: ", sc.defaultMinPartitions

    ########################################################################################################
    ############################################# DATA EXTRACTION ##########################################
    ########################################################################################################
    file_name = path + 'maintenance_data.csv'

    df_nih = spark.read.csv(file_name,sep = ';',header = "true",inferSchema="true")   
    df_nih.show(1)

    #print(df_nih.columns)

    print(df_nih.count())
    ########################################################################################################



    ########################################################################################################
    ######################################## PIPELINE FORMATION ############################################
    ########################################################################################################
    categoricalcolumns = ['team','provider']
    numericalcolumns = ['lifetime', 'pressureInd', 'moistureInd', 'temperatureInd']

    stages = []

    for categoricalcol in categoricalcolumns:
        stringindexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalcol, outputCol = categoricalcol + '_index')
        encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[stringindexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalcol + "_classVec"])

        stages += [stringindexer,encoder]
        #stages += [stringindexer]

    assemblerinputs = [c + "_classVec" for c in categoricalcolumns] + numericalcolumns
    vectorassembler_stage = VectorAssembler(inputCols = assemblerinputs 
                                ,outputCol='features')

    stages += [vectorassembler_stage]

    #output = assembler.transform(df_nih)

    #print(output.show(1))

    indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'broken', outputCol = 'label')

    stages += [indexer]

    #pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [stages,vectorassembler_stage,indexer])

    pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)

    model_pipeline = pipeline.fit(df_nih)

    model_pipeline.write().overwrite().save(pipeline_path)
except:
    print(sys.exc_info())

finally:
    print('stopping spark session')
    spark.stop()
    sc.stop()
```

This is the output:

```
> /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/spark2> ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn
> /opt/nih/sample_spark.py SparkContext Version: 2.3.1.3.0.0.0-1634
> SparkContext Version: 2.3.1.3.0.0.0-1634 Python version:  2.7 Master
> URL to connect to:  yarn Path where Spark is installed on worker
> nodes:  None Retrieve name of the Spark User running SparkContext: 
> spark Application name:  sparkstream Application ID: 
> application_1540925663097_0023 Default level of parallelism:  2
> Default number of partitions for RDDs:  2
> +--------+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+---------+ |lifetime|broken|     pressureInd|     moistureInd|  temperatureInd|
> team| provider|
> +--------+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+---------+ |      56|    
> 0|92.1788540640753|104.230204454489|96.5171587259733|TeamA|Provider4|
> +--------+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-----+---------+ only showing top 1 row
> 
> 999 (<class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'>, Py4JJavaError(u'An error
> occurred while calling o309.save.\n', JavaObject id=o311), <traceback
> object at 0x7f9061c86290>) stopping spark session
```

If I comment the saving part(model_pipeline.write) everything works fine. Please provide your suggestions

Comment: please type `which spark-submit` in your bash console. This should tell you which spark-submit script you are exactly using. I suspect that it is not the same than your ./bin/spark-submit script.
There isn't much we can do to help you with this issue if you don't dig deeper first and learn to investigate what happens exactly on your machine.
Do you use a virtualenv? Which script are you exactly calling? etc.

Comment: Please include full traceback. It is not possible to determine the cause with `Py4JJavaError` alone.

Comment: http://quasiben.github.io/blog/2016/4/15/conda-spark/

Comment: @FurryMachine : which spark-submit command gives the output as ananconda/../ spark-submit. This is the one which is getting executed in the second scenario I have mentioned. When I give explicitly the ./bin/spark-submit it is using the $SPARK_HOME spark-submit. As I mentioned the anaconda one is working fine not the other one. It is using some different parameters/libraries when I try to execute from SPARK_HOME

Comment: @user10465355 : It's too verbose. I am facing some network issues now. will update the question with full logs once the env is up

Comment: @ Prazy: I will go through the link and update you the status

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments

Comment: @Joe, do you have multiple `Hadoop` versions? and can you show the `spark-submit` used?

Comment: Errors commonly happens when the pyspark version does not match the spark installed in SPARK_HOME. You should check that...
Conversely, you should perhaps check which python version are being used in both cases. The PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable can be used to specify it.